# save updated and object inside an array in local storage

Tags: javascript

I am making a todo list. Here is my function that builds my todo list item:

```
function createTodoElement(todo) {
    //todo div
    const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
    todoDiv.classList.add('todos');

    //complete btn
    const completeBtn = document.createElement('button');
    completeBtn.setAttribute('data-id', todo.id);
    completeBtn.classList.add('complete-btn');
    completeBtn.innerText = ('o(-_-)o');
    completeBtn.onclick = completeTodo;


    //todo content
    const todoContent = document.createElement('div');
    todoContent.innerText = todo.content;
    todoContent.classList.add('todo-content');

    //delete button
    const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
    deleteBtn.setAttribute('data-id', todo.id);
    deleteBtn.classList.add('todo-delete-btn');
    deleteBtn.innerText = 'X';
    deleteBtn.onclick = deleteTodo;

    todoDiv.appendChild(completeBtn);
    todoDiv.appendChild(todoContent);
    todoDiv.appendChild(deleteBtn);

    return todoDiv;
}
```

and I am trying to update the todo item's content to say 'done' and update the completed status as 'true' but it doesn't seem to be totally working out for me. here is my function:

```
function completeTodo(e) {
    const btn = e.currentTarget;
    btn.innerText = '\\(^_^)/';

    let targetId = (btn.getAttribute('data-id'));

    console.log(targetId);

    let hasId = ls.getTodoList();

    let item = hasId.find(obj => obj.id == targetId);

    item.content = "done";
    item.completed = 'true';

    localStorage.setItem('content', JSON.stringify(item.content));    
}
```

my object looks somewhat like this: array[{id: 23435352, content: 'make soup', completed: 'false'}, {id:48283749, content: 'study', completed: 'false'}]

everything seems to be working okay but the updating the new data to locale storage. I also want to save the new button inner text. what do I need to change in my function to make this happen?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that your problem is you can't update the todos object? Where do you save it? and why do you just save the content of single items in local storage? Your function seems to be working fine for the adding and updating logic.

Comment: @Gh05d, yes the code I have is not updating the object. I do have a function in a separate module that saves a new list item. But I am  struggling to update an old list item. Because the new content wasn't storing, I haven't tried saving the other items of the object.

Comment: Can you post the code which manages the object? I am a bit confused why you save single todo Items in localStorage instead of the full list. Also, the stringify function is in this case ```localStorage.setItem('content', JSON.stringify(item.content));```not neccessary, as it is already a string.

Comment: @Gh05d, Oh! saving the the whole object does make more sense. would I just do ```localStorage.setItem( targetedID, JSON.stringify(item)); ```?

Comment: Yes, as long as you stringify the item (if it is something else than a string of course) that is no problem.